# How does Java differentiate singly and doubly linkedlists?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

When I studied linkedlists I have learned that there are 2 different types of them - doubly and singly linkedlists. But when I tried to create a linkedlist in java myself I found out that I can't differentiate them, since there is only one class implementing it "LinkedList". So does java treat all linkedlists as doubly linkedlists or I don't understand something? And if I want to create a singly linklist what should I do? Thanks

Comment: The Java `LinkedList` implementation is a doubly-linked list. If you really wanted (for some strange reason) a singly linked list, you'd have to make one yourself (or use a library). But there are not many reasons to [use LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2541560), singly or doubly linked.

Answer (score 1):

If you *read the documentation*, i.e. the javadoc of [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), it starts by saying:

> **Doubly-linked list implementation** of the `List` and `Deque` interfaces.

There is no singly-linked list implementation in the Java Runtime Library. There is no need for one, since the memory savings are too small to really matter.